# Joining SQL Query data with Rest Service data on the fly

Tags: sql-server, rest, caching

I need to merge data from a mssql server and rest service on the fly. I have been asked to not store the data permanently in the mssql database as it changes periodically (caching would be OK, I believe as long as the cache time was adjustable).

At the moment, I am querying for data, then pulling joined data from a memory cache. If the data is not in cache, I call a rest service and store the result in cache.

This can be cumbersome and slow. Are there any patterns, applications or solutions that would help me solve this problem?

My thought is I should move the cached data to a database table which would speed up joins and have the application periodically refresh the data in the database table. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no way to provide an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Denodo. It allows connecting multiple data source and has inbuild caching feature.

http://www.denodo.com/en

Comment: This looks like a good solution to my problem. It appears Pentaho has a similar solution too. Thanks...